Using OpenAI on a vitual enviroment via node.js
I've wanted to try my hand into working with AI and opted to try OpenAI or Olama. I'm currently using Sveltekit to create my website. I've followed a few courses where they used a virual enviroment while creating a Python file, This way you run the LLM on a local machine so that you don't need to top up the amount of tokens you are using. Sadly most of it is in Python and not node.js
I normaly use sveltekit when creating projects so with that info I tried to do the same thing but with node.js. However I cannot get any type of localization to work, only a fetch to the openAI API.
I've heard about something called LM Studio that I believe runs some type of endpoint for you to connect to, something similar to a local enviroment? but i'm not entirely sure how it works or what it provides.
I've tried Using Python as a backend route but didn't make much sense using it in sveltekit,
i've also tried creating a python project which works, but the idea was to get it working within a node.js project for example sveltekit.
This is the code i currently have which fetches the OpenAI API, but again would cost for each use
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

export const actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const form = await request.formData();
        const prompt = form.get('prompt');
        const openai_key = env.OPENAI_KEY2;

        const body = {
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages: [{ role: 'user', content: prompt }]
        };

        const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${openai_key}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }
};


I feel like i've hit a wall on areas to try/research as i've only been looking into AI 2 days ago.
I'm going to try looking more into the LM Studio path, but any advice or direction would help greatly!
If there isn't a way I think maybe just topping up the OpenAI account so that I can progress might be the best option.
